# .Bat line for opening a picture in the same Image Viewer window

Tags: batch-file

We're a little bit in panic, we're not experts and have been spending the day trying to find a line of code that would do what we need in our BAT file.

Basically, we have Windows 7 and we want that when our .bat file is run:

- The image is opened in the Image Viewer
- (In slideshow mode)
- And every time the BAT is run, the new image replaces the old one in the slideshow.

We have this configuration on a Windows XP and it works perfectly, with this line:

```
C:\\WINDOWS\System32\rundll32.exe C:\\Windows\System32\shimgbw.dll,ImageView_Fullscreen %~1
```

However, with Windows 7, impossible to make it work.

- The slideshow doesn't open.
- The next image is opened in a new Image Viewer window

We have tried to:

- Install the XP image viewer, using some tricks found on internet and modifying shimg.dll. Didn't work and now our system32 is quite messed up.
- Install IrfanView as an alternative. Didn't work
- Include "start" in the line, or "/b" to open in same window, but all this didn't really change anything... We're really not experts.

If you can provide any help or insight, that would be fantastic. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by each batch file killing the previous one and thus replacing its image.

If you launch the image with the START command and give a task name; when the batch file launches it should use TASKKILL to delete the previous viewer by name and then START another one.

What program you use to display the image is up to you.

I have some batch subroutines I use, which can be used for this purpose, and I append them.

Put that Program name in serverbinary:

```
SET serverbinary=the.exe
CALL :GetPID ServerPID %servername% "%USERNAME% %serverbinary%"
CALL :KillPID %ServerPID%
START "%USERNAME% %serverbinary%"  "%serverbinary%" %~1 < nul
EXIT /b

:: ------------------------------------------------------------------
:WaitForTask
::
:: Usage: Windowname imagename
:: Wait for a task to finish before continuing
::
set commentsPID=
CALL :GetPID commentsPID %1 %2
REM "%commentsPID%."
IF "%commentsPID%." == "." EXIT /b
echo Waiting for PID %commentsPID% %1 %2 
CALL :Sleep 30
GOTO :WaitForTask

:: ===========================================================================
:GetPID
::  usage: PIDvar imagename windowname 
:: Get the PID of a task
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set _SubArg=
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1,2*" %%a in ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq %~2" /fi "windowtitle eq %~3"  2^>nul ') do @set _SubArg=%%b 
)
( ENDLOCAL
   set %1=%_SubArg%
)
EXIT /B 0

:: ===========================================================================
:KillPID
:: usage: PID
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
if NOT %1. == . taskkill /F /T /PID %1 > nul 2>nul
ENDLOCAL
EXIT /B 0
```